# Where is the TableView loaded in the Navigational-based iPhone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Using XCode's Navigational-based application project type, where is the code that loads the table view that is there by default?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few delegate methods that compose your table view. Apple has a pretty good explanation with a sequence diagram that explains exactly how it is built and what each delegate method does: [link text](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10)

Comment: Very helpful. So what I'm trying to figure out is how in a Navigational-based app template, I can add a view underneath the tableview so display things while the tableview data is loading. I imagine it's a pretty common practice but I'm having trouble getting it done (right).

Comment: I would over-ride loadView()
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW4